# rshiny Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, group

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm a beginner of R and R shiny. I would like to plot "data_plot" (a subset of "data_sum") in R shiny.

[data_sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFQdZ.png)

[data_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrJmI.png)

In R, the following code worked. "start" and "end" are dates that decide which is the "subset".

```
date_range<-unique(data_sum$Category)    
start<-match("2015-10",date_range)
end<-match("2015-12",date_range)

month_plot<-as.vector(date_range[start:end])

data_plot<-subset(data_sum, data_sum$Category %in% month_plot)

ggplot(aes(x= Category, y= x, group=1), data=data_plot) + 
  geom_line(colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=first_thr), linetype="dashed")+
  geom_line(aes(y=second_thr), linetype="dashed")+
  ylim(0,600)
```

According to the R code above, I wrote the following code for R shiny. Now, "start" and "end" are inputs from "ui".

```
date_range<-unique(data_sum$Category) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  start<-reactive({match(input$start_month,date_range)})
  end<-reactive({match(input$end_month,date_range)})
  month_plot<-reactive({date_range[start():end()]})
  data_plot<-reactive({subset(data_sum,data_sum$Month==month_plot())})

  output$monthly_sum <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(aes(x= Category, y= x, group=1), data=data_plot()) + 
      geom_line(colour="red")+
      geom_line(aes(y=first_thr), linetype="dashed")+
      geom_line(aes(y=second_thr), linetype="dashed")+
      ylim(0,600)
    })
}
```

However, I got the error below. Could you please tell me how to fix this?

```
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, group
```

Comment: Could you provide an example which reproduces the error? With just the snippets of code it is not possible to figure out the exact error. Also, please provide a sample data to reproduce the error. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) link.